# Specific Regex Expression for Phone Numbers

Tags: regex

I need to validate that phone numbers are entered in this specific format

+[country_code][space][phone_number], where

```
+ is required
<country_code> is required, 0-9 only, at least 1 digit, max 6 digits
<space> is required
<phone_number> is required, 0-9 only, at least 4 digits, max 20 digits
```

Match: +1 2123333455, +98 343545454, +8733 343433434
Non-Match: +1 (212) 444-3388, 98 3434343, +334 34343 434343

Thanks a bunch! I am not a regex expert.

Comment: You should add the language you plan to use this in and what regex attempts you have made.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\+\d{1,6} \d{4,20}$
```

should do.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/rtha4u/1) are some tests.

If you don't want the country code to begin with a 0 :

```
^\+[1-9]\d{0,5} \d{4,20}$
```

Answer (score -1):

This will validate any international number

```
/\^+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{4,20}$/
```

The number should start with a plus sign followed by the country code and national number

Comment: Your missing your closing delimiter (if OPs language requires them) and is the caret being escaped a typo?

Comment: `{4-20}` is not a range. `The syntax is {min,max}, where min is zero or a positive integer number indicating the minimum number of matches, and max is an integer equal to or greater than min indicating the maximum number of matches.`-http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html